# Sistema fica só em load - Tomcat 9 - Eclipse

Tags: java, java-ee, tomcat

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O sistema carrega só a primeira tela, nenhuma outra pagina carrega, fica só no loading.

Obs:

Quando tento debugar o código, ele não chega no breakpoint.

Ao parar o servidor Tomcat, é retornado os seguintes erros:

```
    WARNING: The web application [cq] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
 com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:43)
set 21, 2018 10:16:19 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
WARNING: The web application [cq] is still processing a request that has yet to finish. This is very likely to create a memory leak. You can control the time allowed for requests to finish by using the unloadDelay attribute of the standard Context implementation. Stack trace of request processing thread:[
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.lang.Object.wait(Unknown Source)
 org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1118)
 org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:106)
 org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
 org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:386)
 org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:87)
 org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:112)
 org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getConnectionForTransactionManagement(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:230)
 org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.begin(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:237)
 org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.begin(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:214)
 org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:52)
 org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1512)
 org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:45)
 org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:170)
 org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:380)
 org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
 org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:427)
 org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:276)
 org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
 org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
 org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
 br.portoseguro.cq.controller.ControleQualidadeController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2830b65f.inicio(<generated>)
 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)
 org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:860)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
 org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
 org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
 org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
 org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
 org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
 org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:412)
 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1385)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)]
set 21, 2018 10:16:19 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [cq] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.springframework.core.NamedThreadLocal] (value [Locale context]) and a value of type [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet$1] (value [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet$1@6265a548]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
set 21, 2018 10:16:19 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [cq] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.springframework.core.NamedThreadLocal] (value [Request attributes]) and a value of type [org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes] (value [org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@2e51ede1]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
set 21, 2018 10:16:19 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
set 21, 2018 10:16:19 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
set 21, 2018 10:16:19 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Cannot get a connection, general error
set 21, 2018 10:16:19 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkStateForResourceLoading
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org.hibernate.internal.util.JdbcExceptionHelper]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org.hibernate.internal.util.JdbcExceptionHelper]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1312)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1300)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1159)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1121)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect$3.convert(MySQLDialect.java:515)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getConnectionForTransactionManagement(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:230)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.begin(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.begin(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1512)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:45)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:170)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:380)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:427)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:276)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
    at br.portoseguro.cq.controller.ControleQualidadeController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2830b65f.inicio(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:860)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:412)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1385)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

set 21, 2018 10:16:19 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkStateForResourceLoading
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org.hibernate.NonUniqueResultException]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org.hibernate.NonUniqueResultException]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1312)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1300)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1159)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1121)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1668)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1700)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:48)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:170)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:380)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:427)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:276)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
    at br.portoseguro.cq.controller.ControleQualidadeController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2830b65f.inicio(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:860)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
```

Comment: Olá Kennedy. Somente com um print da tela há muito pouco que possa ser feito para te ajudar. Recomendo que você crie um [Exemplo Mínimo Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Obrigado pela orientação.

Fiz alguns testes e removi alguns cenários. Criei uma pagina fora do diretório "views" e o consegui chama-la.

dentro do diretório não esta conseguindo.

Comment: E não teve alterações no meu "spring-context".

<bean
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
 </bean>

Comment: @KennedyAnderson os dados de configuração do banco estão corretos? Parece alguma treta de conexão com o banco.

Comment: @adyjr, sim esta tudo certo =\

Comment: Você está migrando uma aplicação que rodava no tomcat 7 ou 8 para o tomcat 9? Isso pode ocorrer por conta da versão do Tomcat, ou versão do Java também.

Comment: @adyjr eu fiz a troca do 8 para 9 se não me engano, pois eram duas maquinas diferentes, e uma utilizava o 9 e outra o 8.

Comment: Mas esse mesmo sistema funcionava no tomcat 8, ou não?

Comment: @adyjr Sim, funcionava. Por algum motivo agora não funciona.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83487/discussion-between-adyjr-and-kennedy-anderson).

Comment: @KennedyAnderson onde está sua biblioteca(drive) de conexão com o banco?
Na pasta lib do tomcat, ou dentro da aplicação?

Comment: @adyjr, desculpe não consigo acessar o chat aqui da empresa.

O drive antes estava dentro da pasta WEB-INF/lib, retirei e adicionei ao Tomcat (Run > Run Configurations > Classpath > "User Entries" + Add External JARs).

Mas o problema permanece.

Comment: @KennedyAnderson poderia verificar se existe outro driver do mesmo tipo que você está usando na pasta lib do tomcat?

Comment: @KennedyAnderson apenas remova a biblioteca de drive da pasta WEB-INF/lib e também do classpath(como citou acima) e faça um teste e diga se o erro persiste ou muda.

Comment: @adyjr

Retorna um erro diferente, logo ao tentar subir o Tomcat..

SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: cq_portoseguro] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory

Comment: @adyjr,  fiz alguns testes em classes, e este problema estava ocorrendo por conta de duas classes no projeto, removi elas e irei refazer.

Obrigado pela a ajuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problema estava ocorrendo devido a problemas em classes DAO, Controller e Service.

Foram removidas e serão refeitas.

Comment: Especificamente na classe DAO, no construtor.